# JetBrains WebStorm Inspection stops working with certain cases

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, inspector

I'm using the *WebStorm IDE* by *JetBrains* to develop an *Angular/Typescript* project. I realized that after some change to my code the inspection results aren't refreshing anymore. And to make matters worse, I couldn't commit/push my changes to the VCS (git). Here's part of the file that seemed to cause the problem:

```
// some code
function onlyNumberAndSeparator(value: string, decimalSeparator: DecimalSeparator = '.'): string {
  return customReplace(value, {searchFor: RegExp(`[^\\d\\${decimalSeparator}]`, 'g'), replacement: ''});
}


// ...some code
```

At first, there seemed to be one quick fix for the issue, and it was to *restart/clear cache* the IDE which seemed to work for a few minutes but after a few changes to the same file, the problem persisted.

**The good news is that I've already found the culprit and I'm going to answer this myself in the first comment.**

Information:

> WebStorm 2021.2.3
> Angular 12
> TypeScript: 4.3.2
> ESLint: 7.26.0

Comment: the part with *\\${decimalSeparator}* seemed to be the culprit. After I changed it to *${decimalSeparator}* _(without the double escaping backslashes)_ everything worked just fine.
__Now the reason I'm not marking this as the answer is that it seems to be a bug in the IDE and I'm just hoping someone might come across this and provide a more definitive solution.__

Comment: If you think it's a bug in the IDE then post it as such to WebStorm Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB